# whole div as link href but not input text

Tags: html, css

How I can make it so that whole div is a link href, but not input text, which is in inside div? This is possible? In this situation I can't type in input.

```
<a href="@Url.Action("Zadania", "Admin", new { id = item.Id })">
   <div id="order">
      <div>
          <b>Zleceniodawca:</b> @item.CustomerName
          <b>Typ zlecenia:</b> @item.OrderType
      </div>
      <b>Postęp pracy: </b><input type="text" name="progress" value="@item.ProgressWork"/> 
   </div>
 </a>
```

Comment: You could perhaps move the `<input>` out of the `<a>` tag and position it where it's supposed to be with CSS.

Comment: also isn't the b element does't seem to be providing any semantic value; you might want to use font-weight CSS property : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/b

Comment: another thing- you're using a link to make behavioral changes which is also semantically inaccurate; I would also suggest using a button element, moving the input outside of the (button) element and styling everything with CSS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your current HTML is invalid for 2 reasons:

1. `<a>` is an inline element and as such can't contain block level elements as `<div>`
2. by [specification](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/single-page.html#the-a-element) `<a>` tag is not allowed to contain interactive content:

> Content model: [Transparent](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/single-page.html#transparent), but there must be no interactive content
>   descendant.

Move the `input` outside of the `a` tag and position it absolutely on top of the link. Everything will still be inside the link, except that the input is now on top of the link and is normally clickable:

```
<div id="order"> 
    <a href="@Url.Action(" Zadania ", "Admin ", new { id = item.Id })">
        <span>
            <b>Zleceniodawca:</b> @item.CustomerName
            <b>Typ zlecenia:</b> @item.OrderType
        </span>
        <b>Postęp pracy: </b>
    </a> 
    <input type="text" name="progress" value="@item.ProgressWork" />
</div>

#order {
    position:relative;
    background:f2f2f2;
    border:1px solid #000;
}
#order > a {
    display:block;
    padding:20px;
    text-align:center;
}
#order input {
    position:absolute;
    top:20px;
    left:50%;
    width:100px;
    margin-left:-50px;
}
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/jFL6R/

Comment: also isn't the b element does't seem to be providing any semantic value; you might want to use font-weight CSS property : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/b

Comment: @AndrewLuhring - `<b>` is still part of HTML and not deprecated in HTML5 - http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/text-level-semantics.html#the-b-element

Comment: I'm aware but using for "utilitarian purposes" aka for presentational purposes, defies the web standards model. http://www.w3.org/community/webed/wiki/The_web_standards_model_-_HTML_CSS_and_JavaScript